# Rasa actions in separate docker container

Tags: docker, exit-code, rasa

I'm currently trying to run rasa on a server. 
I need to have both rasa (i.e. the dialogs) and rasa actions in separate docker containers because we cannot use docker-compose at the moment

Also because of proxy constraints the images (rasa/rasa and rasa/rasa-sdk) are hosted in a private repo.

I am able to run the rasa docker using 
`docker run --name dialogs -d -p 8083:5005 -v $(pwd):/app myRepo/rasa run`

This works fine and I can chat with the bot normally as long as no actions are involved.

When I try running the actions using

`docker run --name actions -d -p 8084:5055 -v $(pwd)/actions:/app/actions myRepo/rasa-sdk:1.5.1 run actions`

the container is immediatly exited with exit code 126 (Command invoked cannot execute)

I'm not changing the wordking dir or anything.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seem I had my actions.py referring to other packages in my project which I hadn't mounted to the container.

So I changed my project structure so that all needed packages are in the actions dir. After that, mounting the actions dir was totally sufficient.

Comment: Hello, could you explain how you manage to run your rasa server and action server on a server? I'm trying to run it on Google App Engine, so far I managed to run the rasa server correctly and communicate with the bot without engaging custom actions. The action server however I can't reach it and only get a 502 bad gateway error. I'm using separate dockerfiles for each, but I don't know why does not work.

Comment: You might try using docker-compose, which makes it way easier to handle all the containers and you're more likely to find good documentation. Check my solution on rasa's forum https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-actions-in-separate-docker-container/22102/4